# Get the days number of the week

Tags: php, date

I would like to get the days of the week compared to the present day. Example :

Today it's sunday 25, i would like to have an array with :

19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 (monday, tuesday, etc)

If we were in the middle of the week, for example Wednesday 21, i should have the same array because it's the same week.

Thanks

Comment: what about multiple cultures? in the usa, Sunday is the first day of the week.

Comment: I didn't know. Sorry. It's for a French website, so in France the week start a monday and finish sunday.

Comment: use the search engine before asking please. This has been answered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
$days = array();
$inputdate = time();

$dayOfInput = date('j', $inputdate); // 25
$weekdayOfInput = date('N', $inputdate); // monday = 1, tuesday = 2, ...

$monday = $dayOfInput - ($weekdayOfInput - 1);


for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
{
  $days[$i] = $monday + $i;
}

var_dump($days);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime).

It accepts relative time strings, for example:

```
strtotime('last Monday');
```

From there you could determine the week for a loop, start and end dates, etc.

**Note:** Be mindful of your usage though. As noted in the comments this logic is not *internationalized*. Furthermore, `strtotime()` is a locale specific function.